# Can a semicolon be used to separate questions?

Tags: punctuation, questions, semicolons

> - Did you see Survivor last night; it was crazy, right?
> - Did you see Survivor last night? It was crazy, right?

Can a semicolon separate questions? Which one is correct?

Comment: Do you have something against commas?

Comment: Normally, this is not done. You would only do that when the first part is truly part of the whole sentence headed by the last part.

Comment: @terdon a comma would only make matters worse, creating a comma splice.

Comment: @RegDwighт yes, that's what AndrewLeach also pointed out. I am far from an expert but it does seem to me that the evils of comma splices are slightly overstated. Especially in cases, as is this one, where the written text is a dialogue which follows the forms of spoken language. See, the very nice quotation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice#Acceptable_uses)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I misusing the semicolon?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42016/am-i-misusing-the-semicolon)

Answer (score 4):

A semicolon ends a statement which is followed by a related statement; it cannot end a question.

It's possible to argue "But I just used it to end a question," but because a semicolon ends a statement, you have turned your question into an ungrammatical statement.

The punctuation mark which indicates a question is a question mark ***?***.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a semicolon used to separate questions.  The semicolon requires almost as much of a pause as a question mark, but without communicating that the statement is a question.  I think an ellipsis or even a comma might have value in writing (e.g., for a very excited person's speech), but to me the semicolon is too awkward to have any use here.

Answer (score -1):

As AndrewLeach said, use of a semicolon turns the first phrase into a statement, not a question. A comma, on the other hand, would be perfect:

> Did you see Survivor last night, it was crazy, right?

Comment: But this is a [*comma splice,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence) which is Not A Good Thing.

Comment: @AndrewLeach good point. Better now?

Comment: It wasn't that comma which was the problem. It's now missing a comma where it needs one (before a question tag) and has a comma where one isn't right (in the middle).

Comment: @AndrewLeach OK I see what you mean now. For some reason it does not bother me. It may be my ignorance (very likely) or it may be that this is dialogue